# WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to automate the download of data from a website with a python script using selenium but I get the following error:

```
"WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined".
```

Code trial:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url="https://www.hlnug.de/?id=9231&view=messwerte&detail=download&station=609"
driver.get(url)
```

Now I define the check-box I want to click and I try to click on it:

```
temp=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="TEMP"]')
action = action_chains.ActionChains(driver)

action.move_to_element(temp)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

I already searched 2 hours on the net without any success. Any idea is therefore welcome!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is the Chromedriver, Chrome, Python version you're using.

Comment: I am using Firefox 60.0 (64 bits), geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64 and python 3.6.3.

Comment: I just tried with Chrome (66.0.3359.139, 64-bit) and the Chromedriver 2.38. I do not get any error message, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two elements that match that locator. The first one is not visible so I'm assuming you want to click on the second.

```
temp = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@value="TEMP"]')[1] # get the second element in collection
action = action_chains.ActionChains(driver)

action.move_to_element(temp)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solves it! I did not see that there were 2 elements, because as you said one of them is not visible. Have a nice evening.

Comment: When you are writing automation, you should always check your locators in the browser. I prefer the Chrome dev tools. Open the page in Chrome and press F12. Use `$$()` to test CSS selectors and use `$x()` to test XPaths. In this case you would run `$x('//input[@value="TEMP"]')` and see that there are two elements returned. Click and hover on the first to see that it's not visible on the page. Click and hover on the second to see that it's visible. Now you can avoid this issue before you even start writing code.

Answer (score 9):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined
```

...implies that the desired *WebElement* might not have **client rects** defined when you tried to interact with it.

As per [**`TypeError: rect is undefined, when using Selenium Actions and element is not displayed.`**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1453779) the main issue is though the desired element with which you are trying to interact [i.e. invoke `click()`] is **present** within the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) but is **not visible** i.e. **not displayed**.

### Reason

The most probhable reasons and solutions are as follows :

- Moving ahead as you are trying to click the element, the desired element may not be interactable at that point of time as some *JavaScript* / *Ajax* call may be still active.
- Element is out of the [**Viewport**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

### Solution

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable as follows :

  ```
  temp = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value="TEMP"]")))
  action = action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
  action.move_to_element(temp)
  action.click()
  action.perform()
  ```
- Use [**`execute_script()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) method to scroll the element in to view as follows :

  ```
  temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value="TEMP"]")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", temp);
  action = action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
  action.move_to_element(temp)
  action.click()
  action.perform()
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried both solutions and none of them worked:
For the first one even by waiting up to 60 seconds I got a timeout error, without much details:
     TimeoutException: Message:
For the second one, I still get the error message:
    WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined

Comment: @Mathador Did you check the link I have shared and the discussion with in the thread?

Comment: Yes, in their case it seems that adding a "action.pause(X)" just before "action.click()" solved the problem. That does not work for me however. I still get the same error message.

Comment: @Mathador As this answer points you to the actual unresolved issue shouldn't it be an accepted answer?

Comment: In their case the issue is solved. In my case not so I cannot consider my question as solved...

Comment: The wait() did it for me. Thanks @DebanjanB

Comment: execute_script() solved it for me, thanks! The element was hidden until it was scrolled over.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too.
but when I wrote the code like below I don't have any problems.

```
    temp=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="TEMP"]')
    action_chains.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(temp).perform() 
    action_chains.ActionChains(driver).click(temp).perform()
```